# How to specify a data type such that inheritance and interface are enforced?

Tags: android, kotlin

How do I specify an (abstract?) data type (or typealias, etc.) `MyType` such that these criteria are enforced:

1. `MyType` is a subclass of `android.view.View`
2. `MyType` implements the interface `MyInterface`

**Use case:** I'd like to have an interface

```
interface OtherInterface {
    fun foo(context: Context): MyType
}
```

where it's possible to add instances returned by `foo` to a `FrameLayout` (using `ViewGroup::addView(view: View)`), as well as calling functions that I have specified in `MyInterface`.

An example of a concrete return type of `foo` that I have in mind is

```
class MyImpl : com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView, MyInterface
```

which is a class which satisfy criteria 1. (since ´LottieAnimationView´ is a subclass of `View`) and 2., i.e. it can be casted to both `View` and `MyInterface`. I'm not sure how I can enforce 1. and 2. in the declaration of `foo`.

If an interface `IView` that contains all public symbols of `View` existed, I would just do: `interface MyType : IView, MyInterface`, but such an interface doesn't exist as far as I know.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You said your criteria was to have `MyType` be an interface, but yet a subclass? That is not possible, you can't have an interface inheriting from a concrete class.

Comment: I'm not quite well versed in Android anymore, especially with respect to subclassing `View`, but is there a problem with `class MyType(...) : View(...), MyInterface { ... }`?

Comment: I was just about to comment exactly that @Joffery. The question seems to describe the implementation...

Comment: I don't think you can because this would suit your criteria `abstract class MyType(...) : View(...), MyInterface` but that would make that any view you want to pass there, is an implementation of `MyType`, which means re-creating the whole view every time. By example a `TextView` you can't, you would have to make an implementation of `MyType` that copy/paste the whole `TextView` code. Unless, if `MyType` is a view group and contains inside a `View`?

Comment: @Joffrey Sorry, I think I failed to fully describe my problem. I have updated the question, and hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: So you want to define ``MyType`` as having a ``View`` superclass and implementing ``MyInterface``? Interfaces can't inherit from classes, so ``MyType`` would have to be a class that subclasses ``View``. If your concrete implementations all subclass *that* you'd be fine, but because you're using classes you don't control as far as I can tell (``LottieAnimationView``) you can't make them inherit from your supertype. You *might* be able to wrangle something with generics, otherwise you might want to just create a wrapper class that holds a ``View``. And ``typealias``es are just labels really

Comment: @cactustictacs I was wondering if generics could be used somehow, but I'm not sure how. Using a wrapper which contains a `View` seems much simpler though. I didn't consider that at all, and I'm happy with that solution. Would you like to post your comment as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: @jazzrc no probs, done! Hope it works for ya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to define `MyType` as having a View superclass and implementing `MyInterface`? Interfaces can't inherit from classes, so `MyType` would have to be a class that subclasses `View`.

If your concrete implementations all subclass that you'd be fine, but because you're using classes you don't control as far as I can tell (`LottieAnimationView`) you can't make them inherit from your supertype.

You *might* be able to wrangle something with generics (I'm not sure you're able to pass a class type and call a constructor to use it as the supertype though), otherwise you might want to just create a wrapper class that holds a `View` and you can put what you like in there.

And typealiases are just labels really. They're great for readability and making your definitions clearer - like having a `phoneNumber` property with a `PhoneNumber` type, where that's just an alias for `String`, or having a `(Int) -> Unit` function type and naming that `ResultListener`. But there's nothing stopping you from just passing a plain old `String` to a `PhoneNumber` property, because they're the same thing, they're not actually separate types or anything. So I don't think there's anything clever you can do with them as far as the type system goes!